# Keynote, numbers and pages not available on El Capitan after reinstalling

Tags: macos, pages, numbers, keynote

I had installed Windows on my MacBook Air after wiping its HDD and then decided to have OS X reinstalled. One thing I noticed is that the office software that had previously showed up in the dock wasn't installed. When I look up Pages on the Appstore it shows a 20€ price tag. How can that be?

Comment: If you had them installed previously, look on the Purchased tab of the App Store and see if you can download them from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was associated with your Apple ID before the OS X reinstallation the reason is that you are haven't logged into the Mac App Store with your Apple ID.

Go to 'Store > Sign In…' and enter your Apple ID credentials. After that you will see "Download" instead of the price for Pages.